# How do I prevent elements from wrapping while using Overflow-X in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

**HTML**

```
<nav class="m-tabs horizontal-scroll p-0 nav card-header-tabs nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <a id="community-tabs-tab-discussion" href="#" role="tab" data-rb-event-key="discussion" aria- 
  controls="community-tabs-tabpane-discussion" aria-selected="true" class="nav-item nav-link 
  active">Discussion</a>
  <a id="community-tabs-tab-about" href="#" role="tab" data-rb-event-key="about" aria- 
  controls="community-tabs-tabpane-about" aria-selected="false" class="nav-item nav-link" 
  tabindex="-1">About</a>
  <a id="community-tabs-tab-members" href="#" role="tab" data-rb-event-key="members" aria- 
  controls="community-tabs-tabpane-members" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" class="nav-item 
  nav-link">Members</a>
  <a id="community-tabs-tab-events" href="#" role="tab" data-rb-event-key="events" aria- 
  controls="community-tabs-tabpane-events" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" class="nav-item 
  nav-link">Events</a>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.horizontal-scroll {
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 200px;
  position:relative;
  white-space: nowrap;/*using nowrap*/
}
```

Instead of keeping each tab inline and adding a horizontal scoll its wrapping them and adding a vertical scroll:

[image: Horizontal Scroll Not Working]

I also tried changing it to 'overflow-x: scroll' and that did not work either.

Comment: consider using `display: flex;`.

Comment: I was specifically instructed to add a horizontal scroll bar

Comment: @Waseem `flex` doesn't allow scrolling.

Comment: How about setting tabs' width to 30% each?

Comment: Not a bad idea but this is for an assignment and I am only allowed to change the div containing the tabs. I was instructed to add a horizontal scroll and nothing else.

Comment: The scroll bar won't show up unless the sum of all child components' width is bigger than the parent's width

Comment: But if its wrapping, shouldn't that already be the case?

Comment: I think you need to show more CSS My bet is the anchors are block elements, not inline

Answer (score 0):

Adding this fixed the issue

```
flex-wrap: nowrap;
```